# Count number of higher lines for each line pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 2 columns DataFrame:

```
positions = pd.DataFrame({"pos" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "mcap" : [1, 4, 3, 2, 5]}, index = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
```

For each index value I need to find amount of points that lay to the upper right corner in 2D world, i.e. for each line I need to count number of lines  which are strictly higher than current line.

So the answer for the example above would be:

```
pd.Series([4, 1, 1, 1, 0], index = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
```

I know how to do that in loop, but that takes much computational time once DataFrame becomes large, thus I'm looking for a more pythonic way to do it.

EDIT. simple solution by loop.

```
answer = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(positions)), index = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
for asset in ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]:
    better_by_signal = positions[positions["pos"] > positions["pos"].loc[asset]].index
    better_by_cap = positions[positions["mcap"] > positions["mcap"].loc[asset]].index
    idx_intersection = better_by_signal.intersection(better_by_cap)
    answer[asset] = len(idx_intersection)
```

Comment: What should happen in case of equality, e.g., mcap : [1, 4, 3, 2, 4]? Are there any NaN values in your dataframe?

Comment: @Mr.T no NaNs, actually each value in mcap and pos is unique, thus you can assume anything (while I believe that that should not change the answer much).

Comment: if possible please post your solution you have with loop included with your question, that should help

Comment: @AJS I have attached loop solution.

Comment: @ArtyomAkselrod Some numpy/pandas function return unexpected results, when NaN values are present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could employ `numpy` broadcasting to find all positive difference pairs for the x-axis (`pos`) and y-axis (`mcap`):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

positions = pd.DataFrame({"pos" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "mcap" : [1, 4, 3, 2, 5]}, index = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])

arrx = np.asarray([positions.pos])
arry = np.asarray([positions.mcap])
positions["count"] = ((arrx - arrx.T > 0) & (arry - arry.T > 0)).sum(axis = 1)

print(positions)
```

Sample output

```
   pos  mcap  count
a    1     1      4
b    2     4      1
c    3     3      1
d    4     2      1
e    5     5      0
```

Comment: I've checked speed of all solutions suggested, this one is the best, works much faster comparing to the loop solution from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use map instead of looping over the index, this should work:-

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np

  positions = pd.DataFrame({"pos" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "mcap" : [1, 4, 3, 2, 5]}, index = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
  answer = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(positions)), index = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])

  def set_pos(asset):
     better_by_signal = positions[positions["pos"] > positions["pos"].loc[asset]].index
     better_by_cap = positions[positions["mcap"] > positions["mcap"].loc[asset]].index
     idx_intersection = better_by_signal.intersection(better_by_cap)
     return len(idx_intersection)

  len_intersection = map(set_pos, answer.index.tolist())
  final_answer = pd.Series(len_intersection, index = answer.index.tolist())
```

Comment: This solution gives just a small speed increase comparing to the loop solution suggested in question.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead of a for-loop use a list comprehension like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


positions = pd.DataFrame({"pos": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                          "mcap": [1, 4, 3, 2, 5]}, 
                         index=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]) 

# gives you a list:
answer = [sum(np.sum((positions - positions.iloc[i] > 0).values, axis=1) ==
              2) for i in range(len(positions))]

# convert list to a `pd.Series`:
answer = pd.Series(answer, index=positions.index)
```

Comment: This solution seems to be even worse comparing to loop one mentioned in the question. It worked almost 4 times slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can use convolutions. Convolution does something like this (more info [here](http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Feature_extraction_using_convolution)):

[image]

It will go through the matrix multipling your filter or pad by the elemnts of the matrix and then adding them together in this case.

For this question, lets first add a new element `f` to the dataframe so at least one row have more than one element.

```
>> positions

   pos  mcap
a    1     1
b    2     4
c    3     3
d    4     2
e    5     5
f    3     2
```

The positions can be also seen as:

```
df = pd.crosstab(positions['pos'], positions['mcap'], 
                 values=positions.index, aggfunc=sum)

df

mcap    1    2    3    4    5
pos                          
1       a  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2     NaN  NaN  NaN    b  NaN
3     NaN    f    c  NaN  NaN
4     NaN    d  NaN  NaN  NaN
5     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    e


df_ones = df.notnull() * 1

mcap  1  2  3  4  5
pos                
1     1  0  0  0  0
2     0  0  0  1  0
3     0  1  1  0  0
4     0  1  0  0  0
5     0  0  0  0  1
```

We can create a window that slides through `df_ones` and sum the number of elements that fall under the window. This is called 'convolution' (or correlation).

Now let us create a window that avoids the upper left corner element (so it is not counted) and convolute it with our `df_ones` to get the result:

```
pad = np.ones_like(df.values)
pad[0, 0] = 0

pad

array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=object)


counts = ((signal.correlate(df_ones.values, pad,
                            mode='full')[-df.shape[0]:,
                                         -df.shape[1]:]) * \ 
          df_ones).unstack().replace(0, np.nan).dropna(
          ).reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'count'})

   mcap  pos  count
0     1    1    5.0
1     2    3    3.0
2     2    4    1.0
3     3    3    1.0
4     4    2    1.0

positions.reset_index().merge(counts, 
                              how='left').fillna(0
     ).sort_values('pos').set_index('index')

       pos  mcap  count
index                  
a        1     1    5.0
b        2     4    1.0
c        3     3    1.0
f        3     2    3.0
d        4     2    1.0
e        5     5    0.0
```

All in a function:

```
def count_upper(df):
    df = pd.crosstab(positions['pos'], positions['mcap'],
                     values=positions.index, aggfunc=sum)
    df_ones = df.notnull() * 1

    pad = np.ones_like(df.values)
    pad[0, 0] = 0

    counts = ((signal.correlate(df_ones.values, pad,
                                mode='full')[-df.shape[0]:,
                                             -df.shape[1]:]) * df_ones)
    counts = counts.unstack().replace(0, np.nan).dropna(
    ).reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'count'})

    result = positions.reset_index().merge(counts,
                                         how='left')
    result = result.fillna(0).sort_values('pos').set_index('index')
    return result
```

For your example the result would match your expected result:

```
positions = pd.DataFrame({"pos" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                          "mcap" : [1, 4, 3, 2, 5]},
                         index = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
>> count_upper(positions)
       pos  mcap  count
index                  
a        1     1    4.0
b        2     4    1.0
c        3     3    1.0
d        4     2    1.0
e        5     5    0.0
```

Comment: This code does not work as `NameError: name 'signal' is not defined`